# How to change multiple XML element contents from DevOps

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-pipelines

I have a web.config file that has the following elements:

```
<client>
 <endpoint address="url_1" />
 <endpoint address="url_2" />
 <endpoint address="url_3" />
</client>
```

Now, I want to change it depending on the environment that I am deploying to. I have created a release pipeline that deploys to my dev and prod environment on Azure, I am using [XML Variable Substitution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=Classic#xmlvarsubs) to change whatever variables I need such as connectionString in my prod environment.

I want to change the 3 endpoint elements contents in the web.config file in my PROD environment as well.

For instance, it shoud look like this in the respective environments:

#### DEV:

```
<client>
 <endpoint address="url_1" />
 <endpoint address="url_2" />
 <endpoint address="url_3" />
</client>
```

#### PROD:

```
<client>
 <endpoint address="url_4" />
 <endpoint address="url_5" />
 <endpoint address="url_6" />
</client>
```

I looked into [XML File Transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=Classic#xmltransform), and I don't want to add onto the file. I want to remove `url_1, url_2, url_3` and replace them with `url_4, url_5, url_6`

Is there a way on the release pipeline to accomplish this task without breaking the variable substitutions that I have added in place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, if you want to change the multiple XML element contents during running the pipeline, I recommend that you  use the extension task Magic Chunks. This task can transform configuration files during the build process.

You can install [Magic Chunk](https://github.com/sergeyzwezdin/magic-chunks)s task to your organization, then add it to your pipeline. It tested your web.config with below example settings for magic chunk task:
[image]

Regarding the parameters **Path** and **transformations**: You need to specify your own configuration file path and required transformations.

Below is my test, you can refer to it:
[image]
[image]

After the pipeline runs successfully, we check the artifact file and  find that the elements in the config file have changed.
[image]

Comment: How would I use magic chunks to change multiple lines? Can I add a JSON config line where I match it to the name attribute somehow and change the address attribute value?

Comment: You can use magic chunks to change multiple lines. For example:

{
   "key1": "value1",
   "key2": "value2"
}


Magic Chunks is easy to use tool to config transformations for JSON, XML and YAML.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Replace tokens task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens&targetId=369194ee-6a5a-406b-add1-c27b1c293b29) to achieve this. Note that you will have to save these variable values in the pipeline/Variable group. *For eg: Value of `url1` will be `url_1` scoped to Dev Stage.*

**XML file setup:**

```
<client>
 <endpoint address="#{url1}#" />
 <endpoint address="#{url2}#" />
 <endpoint address="#{url3}#" />
</client>
```

### **Result:**

**Dev:**

```
<client>
 <endpoint address="url_1" />
 <endpoint address="url_2" />
 <endpoint address="url_3" />
</client>
```

**Prod:**

```
<client>
 <endpoint address="url_4" />
 <endpoint address="url_5" />
 <endpoint address="url_6" />
</client>
```